# How to use Doxygen with Mermaid diagrams embedded in markdown document content?

Tags: markdown, doxygen, mermaid

**Example: README.md**

````
# Objective
How can Doxygen generate content that includes Mermaid diagrams embedded in GitHub markdown files (*.md)?

# Mermaid Diagram
```mermaid
sequenceDiagram
    Alice->>John: Hello John, how are you?
    John-->>Alice: Great!
    Alice-)John: See you later!
```

# PlantUML Diagram
PlantUml works well with Doxygen.  Thank you!

```plantuml
@startuml
Alice -> Bob: Authentication Request
Bob --> Alice: Authentication Response

Alice -> Bob: Another authentication Request
Alice <-- Bob: Another authentication Response
@enduml
```
````

The goal is to **NOT** have to create standalone [Mermaid diagram files (*.mdd) and reference from a markdown document](https://github.com/tttapa/doxygen-mermaid).

The goal is to use Mermaid like PlantUml can be used with Doxygen.  PlantUml works great with Doxygen.  However, Mermaid has an advantage that it is rendered in browser when a markdown document is viewed in GitLab, Azure DevOps Wiki and VS Code markdown preview.

[Azure DevOps git is not supported unfortunately] (Vote here)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-mermaid-diagrams-in-markdown-file-preview/817244).

Mermaid has a disadvantage compared to PlantUml since diagrams are not created from markdown files included in Doxygen.

I expect this may be a challenging since Mermaid uses browser side rendering.

Thank in advance for any tips on using Mermaid with Doxygen.

Answer (score 0):

I am building a documentation for a C code based project and I was interested on this same question. I have a following suggestion to generate mermaid diagrams embedded into the markdown documentation by utilization of doxygen input filters.

The suggestion is provided in a forked github repo https://github.com/tahyx/doxygen-mermaid/tree/feature/md_mermaid_example

The bottom line is to add an [input filter](https://github.com/tahyx/doxygen-mermaid/blob/985892dcc2acad7b88000fec960b8e3324dd6657/Doxyfile#L15) into doxygen that is a [shell script](https://github.com/tahyx/doxygen-mermaid/blob/985892dcc2acad7b88000fec960b8e3324dd6657/doxygen_filter_mermaid.sh) that converts the fenced mermaid code blocks into html  elements. (Note: the changes in header and footer html files mentioned [here](https://github.com/tttapa/doxygen-mermaid#readme) are also needed).

That seems to work pretty well for some mermaid diagrams but for others doxygen seems to make modifications also to the text inside the html  tags which results into an error (reported by the mermaid js plugin) or otherwise unintended result. This can be seen in the generated document of communication.md by looking into source code of the generated html page (some unintended html tags are generated inside the  elements). I did not figure out any workarounds to these cases.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for writing an answer. Most great answers do not only show how a problem *could* be solved but they do provide an *actual* solution. Note also that links can become inaccessible so it's best to write an answer to be self-contained and provide links for references.